# How to test API Controller with xUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xunit.net

I am new to unit testing and .net. I want to test an api controller, which returns and IEnumerable.
What is the best way to test this controller? Do you have any suggestions?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PersonController 
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetListOfPerson([FromQuery] FilterRequest request)
    {
        return new Person[]
        {
            new()
            {
              Name ="Peter"
              Age = "23"
              
            },
            new()
            {
              Name ="John"
              Age = "54"        
            }
        }
        .Where(person=> request.MatchesFilter(person))
        .Skip(request.Page * request.ItemsPerPage)
        .Take(request.ItemsPerPage);
    }
    ...
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello Trap, I think for those cases, the commonly used tests are API tests. Unit tests are usually meant for specific methods or flow's in a "lower layer" so to speak.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_testing For this you could use Postman :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so hard. Create a `TestClass` which have one instance of your `Controller`. Call the controller's method to test.

My snippet :

```cs
public class TestClass {
 private readonly PersonController personController;

 public TestClass(){
  // you can setup any mock, initialization to test class if needed
   personController = new PersonController();
 }

 [Fact]
 public void GetListOfPersonTest(){
   // create instance of FilterRequest to controller
   var result = personController.GetListOfPerson(..filterRequestHere..); // call the method

   Assert.IsType<IEnumerable<Person>>(result); // check the type of returned result
 }
}
```

You can read more of [Assert here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert?view=mstest-net-1.3.2)

Comment: Sorry, but what are testing here?

Comment: @PeterCsala  I think the answer is clear. But if you don't aggree with me, feel free to downvote or edit my answer.

Comment: The thing is because of `IsType` this test will fail. `IsAssignableFrom` is more flexible assertion and it can accept not just `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` but `System.Linq.Enumerable+ListPartition` as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a separate class for your PersonControllerTest
2. Create an instance of your PersonController inside PersonControllerTest
3. Invoke your method/function

   ```
        [Fact]
        public void GetListOfPerson_ShouldReturn()
        {

            var response = personController.GetListOfPerson(YOUR PARAM);
            //Time to Assert 
            Assert.True(response.Count() == 2);
            Assert.NotNull(response);
            //etc...
        }
   ```

This might be a help as well.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-5.0